# Is there a software that can show me how to draw objects from my images?

Tags: images, software-recommendation, drawing

I am looking for a program that can take an arbitrary image and show a step-by-step guide how to draw objects from it.

I mean a guide like this:
[image]

Does such program exist? Is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea how such a thing would even work with any arbitrary image... I think you may be expecting a bit much.

Comment: I think it could be possible nowadays, at least on "easy" pictures. But it would probably take at least a bunch of months to make it work as well you want.

Answer (score 2):

No, no such software exists. Indeed if a computer program could decompose a image with this kind of accuracy that would mean millions if not hundreds of millions losing their job. This is smack in the middle of artificial intelligence land. Also this would devalue the drawing skill to a point where whats the point of doing it.

I mean computers can not even easily deduce where the lines in a simple signature are let alone try to reproduce the drawing order of one. See [How to convert a signature from JPG to vector strokes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/how-can-i-convert-a-jpg-signature-into-strokes), they barely get the job done.