# Convert a pen signature like a marker or fountain pen using the tools on line

Tags: vector, tools, image-editing, image-format, image-trace

Starting from this old question, [How to convert a signature from JPG to vector strokes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/how-to-convert-a-signature-from-jpg-to-vector-strokes), or other similar, without to have installed anything on my notebook, is there the possibility to trasform my signature written with a ballpoint pen and make it as if I use a marker or fountain pen?

Here there is a crop of my signature:

[image]

I hope not to disturb you.

I use only Paint and Microsoft Picture Manager of Office and I hope that exist a free online tool without registration that can do this.

Comment: If you don't want to install anything, you need to tell us which software you already have on your notebook. Do you have Adobe CC? What will you use it for? For the web or for print? And since it's your own signature can't you just make a new one with a marker or fountain pen?

Comment: @Wolff Thank you very much for your comment. I not have Adobe CC but only Paint and Microsoft Picture Manager of Office. I have any signature written with a marker but this signature I like very much. I would to put this signature into a .doc document and print with pdf-creator to have a file pdf, but the result with this signature it is not very good.

Comment: There are online services which can trace vectors from raster images. You can find them by searching on google for "online vector tracing". I can't recommend any as I haven't tried any of them. If you want free software, [Inkscape](https://www.inkscape.org) has such functionality. It installs in just a few minutes.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi :-) I not put to install Inkscape. I have an old notebook, OS W7 32bit, 3MB of memory :-(. I have tried https://it.vectormagic.com/, https://www.autotracer.org/ (now) but it fills me the a with black. Peraphs this tools is good: https://online.rapidresizer.com/tracer.php. I'm trying some tools....But if you know one very very good, can you put an answer....I like upvotes the questions/answers (see my profiles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the online Photoshop clone [Photopea](https://www.photopea.com/).

- Drag and drop the image into Photopea.
- Use *Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur* to smoothen the image a bit:
  [image]
- Use *Filter > Other > Maximum* to make the lines a little bit thinner:
  [image]
- Use *Filter > Other > Minimum* to make the lines a little bit wider again:
  [image]
- Use *Filter > Noise > Dust & Scratches* to remove the grainy details:
  [image]
- Use *Image > Adjustments > Threshold* to make the image black and white again:
  [image]

I don't know if the image you posted is in full resolution. If the original is in larger resolution it might not work as intended.

Be aware that the image you have is 1-bit (only black and white) without anti-aliasing. So if the resolution isn't high enough in the final physical size you end up using the image, the edges could look jagged.

Comment: Spectacular and I give now and the next future.....thank you very very much.